# Use python to convert text file containing MQSC into a csv format output file

Tags: python, csv

I am learning python and have been trying various code solutions on this great site, but just can't get anything to work properly with the format of MQSC data, so as a example input file...

```
NAME(XX.XXX.XXX)        PARM1 (any data)

PARM2( )            PARM3(data)

PARM4(data)         PARM5(data(more data))

NAME(YY.XXX.XXX)        PARM1 (any data)

PARM2(long data could contain NAME)

PARM3(data(moredata))   PARM4( )

PARM5(data)         

NAME(ZZ.XXX.XXX)        PARM2(data)

PARM3(data)
```

…and so on…

I am trying to write the output file in the format of…

```
NAME(XX.XXX.XXX),PARM1 (any data),PARM2( ),PARM3(data),PARM4(data),PARM5(data(more data))

NAME(YY.XXX.XXX),PARM1 (any data),PARM2(long data could contain NAME),PARM3(data(moredata)),PARM4( ),PARM5(data)

NAME(ZZ.XXX.XXX),PARM2(data),PARM3(data)
```

So a new line would always start with NAME if in col 1 only , spaces within brackets need to be preserved, spaces between PARMS/LABELS need to be removed and separated by comma’s.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try that you might modify to suit your needs. There are two functions:

- `lexer()` - eats up the input and always returns a token and a buffer. The token is either `TOK_EOF` (end of input), or `TOK_STRING` (such as NAME or PARM3), or `TOK_PARLIST` (stuff in parentheses, such as `(data)`).
- `parser()` - implements a simple grammar. It calls the `lexer()` and always expects either a `TOK_EOF` or a `TOK_STRING`. In the case of `TOK_STRING` it calls `lexer()` again and requires a token `TOK_PARLIST`

In the `parser()` the output is generated in CSV format, using a variable `output_generated` to determine whether or not to output a newline etc. When the `parser()` sees a token `TOK_STRING` with value `'NAME'` then it forces output to a new line.

Given your input, the output is as follows. You might want to re-check whether all spaces between the elements are preserved or removed as you require.

```
NAME(XX.XXX.XXX),PARM1(any data),PARM2( ),PARM3(data),PARM4(data),PARM5(data(more data)),
NAME(YY.XXX.XXX),PARM1(any data),PARM2(long data could contain NAME),PARM3(data(moredata)),PARM4( ),PARM5(data),
NAME(ZZ.XXX.XXX),PARM2(data),PARM3(data)
```

Finally, here's the code, hope it's clear enough for you to build on.

```
input = """
NAME(XX.XXX.XXX) PARM1 (any data)
PARM2( ) PARM3(data)
PARM4(data) PARM5(data(more data))
NAME(YY.XXX.XXX) PARM1 (any data)
PARM2(long data could contain NAME)
PARM3(data(moredata)) PARM4( )
PARM5(data)
NAME(ZZ.XXX.XXX) PARM2(data)
PARM3(data)
"""

TOK_EOF     = 0     # no more input
TOK_STRING  = 1     # NAME or PARMx string seen
TOK_PARLIST = 2     # ( ...stuff... ) seen
def lexer():
    global input

    buf = ''

    while True:
        if len(input) == 0:
            return TOK_EOF, ''

        if input[0].isalnum():
            while input[0].isalnum():
                buf += input[0]
                input = input[1:]
            return TOK_STRING, buf

        if input[0] == '(':
            parlev = 1
            buf = '('
            input = input[1:]
            while parlev > 0:
                char = input[0]
                input = input[1:]
                buf += char
                if char == ')':
                    parlev -= 1
                elif char == '(':
                    parlev += 1
            return TOK_PARLIST, buf

        if input[0] == ' ' or input[0] == '\n':
            input = input[1:]
        else:
            raise Exception('lexer encountered ' + input[0] + ' at input ' +
                            input)

def parser():
    output_generated = False
    while True:
        tok, buf = lexer()

        if tok == TOK_EOF:
            if output_generated:
                print()
            break
        if tok == TOK_STRING:
            if output_generated:
                print(',', end='', sep='')
                if buf == 'NAME':
                    print()
            print(buf, end='')
            tok, buf = lexer()
            if tok != TOK_PARLIST:
                raise Exception('parlist expected, got token ' + str(tok) +
                                ' and buffer ' + buf + ' at input: ' + input)
            print(buf, end='', sep='')
            output_generated = True

parser()
```